# How to change jqgrid searchoptions "Select options" description

Tags: jqgrid

How can I change search options description on filter row ?

Can I change it on searchoptions function ?

```
$("#project_jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'PNInProcess.php',
    editurl: 'PNInProcessEdit.php',
    mtype: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    page: 1,
    colModel: [
        {   label : "Status",
            name: 'Status',
            //key: true,
            width: 80,
            align: 'center',
            editable: true,
            edittype:'select',
            editoptions: { 
                value: "0:V;:"
            },
            stype: "select",
            searchoptions: {
                multiple:true,
                dataInit : function (elem) {},
                value: {'O':'O','X':'X','!':'!','V':'V'}
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

The default description is "Select options".[1](https://ppt.cc/fDsLjx)

I want to change it.

Thanks a lot

**I got solution: 

add "noneSelectedText" in dataInit. Like this**

```
searchoptions: { 
   dataInit : function (elem) { 
      noneSelectedText: "ABC"
   }
}
```

Comment: This is maybe somewhere in your code. Please post what do your dataInit function. I tested your code and it does not show me this description.

Comment: Hello Tony ,thank you your reply. I didn’t describe it very clearly. I just want to change the description of the red frame of the picture. But I don't know where I can change it.

Comment: I do not understand. How is this value build ed? I have copy your code one to one, but I do not see such text. Please explain in detail

Comment: "Select options" default show on the filter row(such as picture attachments). It's not related to my code. But I want to change this description(Select options). I think it is possible to add some code to searchoptions or dataInit or other functions to change this description.

Comment: Could you please prepare a example in [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net), which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hi Tony! I try and success. I add "noneSelectedText" in dataInit. Like this searchoptions: {
 dataInit : function (elem) {
  noneSelectedText: "ABC"
 }
}